# Can't Get CSRF Token to Appear on a Django Template/View

Tags: django, django-csrf

I'm trying to use a Django `ListView` sub-class to generate a page with a form on it.  It's an old school manual HTML form, not a Django-generated one (though I do also have a Django-generated form elsewhere on the same page).  Since Django bakes CSRF authentication in, I need to include the CSRF token in that form in order to make it work.

However, I'm not having much luck, even after looking at several related Stack Overflow posts (and fixing things accordingly).

Basically I've got a `get` method on a `ListView` subclass, and  I've used the method decorator to decorate it with the CSRF decorator:

```
class FooView(ListView):
    @method_decorator(ensure_csrf_cookie)
    def get(self, request):
        # code for otherwise working view
```

In my template I have:

```
<form>
{% csrf_token %}
```

However, when I view the source of the page after it's been rendered, I just see:

```
<form>
```

(no CSRF token).

I'm not explicitly adding the CSRF token to the context because I'm using `ListView`, and as per https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/csrf:

> If you are using generic views or contrib apps, you are covered already

I'm sure I'm just missing something basic, but any help explaining what that might be would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you add a `middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` in your settings?

Comment: I think you'll need to actually show the code for the `get` method.

Comment: @Andrey Zarubin Well technically I didn't add it, it was already there, but yes.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman when I went to paste my `get` method in I realized the problem: I was using render_to_response, which (I take it) avoids `ListView`'s built-in providing of the CSRF token and evidently means that I needed to provide it myself (when I did, everything worked).  Could you please put your comment in the form of an answer (something to the effect of "you must be doing something wrong with your get method, such as using render_to_response` when you should be calling the super method") and then I can accept it and give you the points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need import this:

```
from django.template import RequestContext
```

and then use it like so:

```
def example():

    # Some code

    return render_to_response('my_example.html', {
    'Example_var':my_var
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

This will force a `{% csrf_token %}` to appear.